# How to import different header file depending some conditions

Tags: ios, file, header

There're two header files,for example a.h  and b.h.
And I need to import them into myClass.m depending some conditions.

If(A),then import a.h.
If(B),then import b.h.

Coz there's many same definition in a.h and b.h. So I can't import both of them at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of using different headers for different targets you can use something like this

```
#ifdef A_STATE
#import "a.h"
#else
#import "b.h"
#endif
```

where A_STATE can be set as preprocessor macros for target

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try it .